# GCP logging query issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to collect logs to be handled as incidents / SCC audits in case any tampering with firewall rules are logged.

Found out that something like this does the trick more or less:

`resource.type=gce_firewall_rule AND protoPayload.methodName=v1.compute.firewalls.patch OR protoPayload.methodName=v1.compute.firewalls.insert OR protoPayload.methodName=v1.compute.firewalls.update`

However, this only solves the issue partially, because methods on GCP may differ. And rules that were added in the past and ones that will be added in the future may use different version suffixes:

v1, beta, alpha, v2... etc.

I unfortunately couldn't find any documentation that helps find a condition that can include everything at methodName value.

Something like:

protoPayload.methodName="*.compute.firewalls.update" or "%compute.firewalls.update"

Thank you!

Comment: @DazWilkin's answer is excellent and will answer your question. I recommend capturing everything on just the resource `resource.type=gce_firewall_rule` All changes should be detected and analyzed or reviewed. Detecting that something changed is not enough. You must also maintain the previous state to know what changed and the effect of that change.

Comment: @JohnHanley, unfortunately using only the resource.type only will also match the .list method, which is not what we want to match as an incident. but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Logging has a comprehensive [query language](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language#regular-expressions).

You have various options:

- If you have a definitive list `OR`: `protoPayload.methodName = ("v1" OR "v1beta1" OR ...)`
- If you want to use a [regular expression](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language#regular-expressions)
- If you want anything `protoPayload.methodName:*`

Comment: Thank you. I checked for an expression that could match protoPayload.methodName=everythinghere(be it v1, beta, alpha, v3, v2...etc,etc) .compute.firewalls.method(patch,insert, update) to no avail. Sorry, maybe what i want to achieve is a little blurry. 

I basically would liketo achieve this:

protoPayload.methodName=ALL.compute.firewalls.update/create/insert

The last option protoPayload.methodName:* doesn't work causes it also alerts when someone views a firewall. 

Seems like i don't have the necessary knowledge nor ideas for it. :) This is my first week of ever touching gcp

Comment: maybe: protoPayload.methodName=~("patch" OR "insert" OR "update" or "create")

Comment: It's difficult for me to provide a definitive answer as I don't use Firewalls. You can try matching on substring (`protoPayload.methodName:compute.firewalls`) to capture all API versions **and** all methods (including `list`) and then `NOT protoPayload.methodName:"compute.firewalls.list"`) **or** enumerate the methods using substring `protoPayload.methodName:"compute.firewalls.patch" OR protoPayload.methodName:"compute.firewalls.insert" OR ...`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed input. I will play around different expressions.